# How to filter nested arrays using javascript or lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have soo many nested arrays like this

```
[['branch',12,'name','cofee'],['state',15,'name','tea'],['Country',12,'name','tea']['branch',15,'name','Choclate']]
```

I want to filter array which is having the element **branch** so result ll be like this

```
[['branch',12,'name','cofee'],['branch',15,'name','Choclate']]
```

can anybody help me on this

Answer (score 3):

You should provide a predicate to `filter` which checks if the array contains `'branch'`.

If you can use ES6, I would do:

```js
const data = [
  ['branch', 12, 'name', 'cofee'],
  ['state', 15, 'name', 'tea'],
  ['Country', 12, 'name', 'tea'],
  ['branch', 15, 'name', 'Choclate']
];

const processed = data.filter(d => (d.indexOf('branch') > -1));

console.log(processed);
```

If you can't use ES6:

```js
const data = [
  ['branch', 12, 'name', 'cofee'],
  ['state', 15, 'name', 'tea'],
  ['Country', 12, 'name', 'tea'],
  ['branch', 15, 'name', 'Choclate']
];

const processed = data.filter(function (d) {
  return d.indexOf('branch') > -1;
});

console.log(processed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma in your array.  You are dealing with a 2d array, a simple object to work with really.  Just use a for loop looking for item [0] in each array.

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
var myArray = [['branch',12,'name','cofee'],['state',15,'name','tea'],['Country',12,'name','tea'],['branch',15,'name','Choclate']];

var filteredArray = [[]];

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if(myArray[i][0] === 'branch'){
        filteredArray.push(myArray[i]);

    }
}

var t = document.createTextNode(filteredArray);

div.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a modern approach is ;

```js
var data = [['branch',12,'name','cofee'],['state',15,'name','tea'],['Country',12,'name','tea'],['branch',15,'name','Choclate']],
filtered = data.filter(f => f.includes("branch"));
console.log(filtered);
```